# How does one turn on diagnostic and/or progress logging with firebase-tools run as a node module?

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

I have not been able to find any reference for the options passed into the node module version of firebase-tools. How do one turn on diagnostic logging or progress output? The github README for firebase tools only says:

> The Firebase CLI can also be used programmatically as a standard Node module. Each command is exposed as a function that takes an options object and returns a Promise.

and has only the example:

```
client.deploy({
  project: 'myfirebase',
  token: process.env.FIREBASE_TOKEN,
  cwd: '/path/to/project/folder'
}).then(function() {...
```

It would be really nice to get complete docs. The source code wasn't much help.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a good way to see progress via the programmatic API for the Firebase CLI right now. Your best bet would be to instead use `spawn` or similar to run it as a process and simply capture the stdout.

We'd like to improve this in the future but there are no concrete plans of what it will look like yet.

Answer (score 0):

To see the complete list of keys off of the `client` object, see [`commands/index.js`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/master/commands/index.js)

In terms of what options to pass in, that is definitely hard to figure out. This seems like a great chance to [submit an issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/new) requesting specific improvements to documentation, or take a shot at documenting it yourself and submit a PR.

Comment: It's not the key of client I'm after, it's the key of the options object passed to functions hanging off client (e.g `.deploy()`), like `project`, `token` and `cwd` in the example.